# Converting a mixed fraction to a decimal

Tags: python, python-2.7

Designation variable is a string either 'M5' for a metric (mm) measurement or '1/2' for inch. It gets a little complicated with '1 1/2' or measurements larger then an inch.

Here is what I have right now related to the inch measurement issue:

```
   decimal = 1.0 * float(designation)
```

Also, I have looked through fractions module without any luck.

Comment: This isn't clear. Are you trying to convert string representations of mixed fractions to decimal values? If so, much of your question is irrelevant detail.

Comment: yes, the designation variable must be a string to hold both 'M5' and '1 1/2'.

Comment: `eqv = designation[1:] * 0.0393701` here, you multiply a string with a floating point number... Also, why `0.0039...`? What is `M`? Millimeter?

Comment: the units for the 'M5' were millimeters. to John's point that was extraneous so I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could get you part of the way there:

```
def mixed_to_float(x):
    return float(sum(fractions.Fraction(term) for term in x.split()))
```

for example,

```
>>> mixed_to_float('1/3')
0.3333333333333333
>>> mixed_to_float('1 1/2')
1.5
```